# How to get primary key and save it in another table with a different page

Tags: laravel-8

I have a table am calling stands with pre-existing data, on each particular record there is an option to assign that stand to an entity called exhibitor. The Assign button takes me to another page where am able to fill in information about the exhibitor who now owns that stand.
[Exhibitor form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZOR0.jpg)[Stand table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSRcV.jpg)

How do I apply the one to one relationship in a case such as this

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing the primary key you need as a parameter in the route to your following page. You can then create an input in your form to hold that value and retrieve it with your other inputs.

Comment: Sure thanks I will try that.